# How do I disprove that $|\mathcal P([0,1]) \setminus \mathcal P((0,1))| > |\mathcal P(\mathbb{N})|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to disprove this proposition $|\mathcal P([0,1]) \setminus \mathcal P((0,1))| > |\mathcal P(\mathbb{N})|$, where $\mathcal P (X)$ is the power set of $X$, but I am not sure how. I hope someone here could help me, thanks.

Comment: Step 1: Talk to your classmates. Step 2: Check the duplicate, and its duplicate.